# Opencart 2 - For guests price with tax for logged in without tax

Tags: opencart, price, tax

I need your help, now in Store settings prices with tax!
So it is okey.
But when customer logged in, i need it without tax only on product page and in category.
How can i do this?
Thank you!

Comment: Look for module, u can't do it from Opencart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello @Ivan go to the catalog/controller/product.php and in your `public function index()`  search for the

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) { 

    $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')), $this->session->data['currency']);  `

    }else {  
     $data['price'] = false;
    }
```

**Change it to :**

```
if ($this->customer->isLogged() || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) { 
    $data['price'] = $this->currency->format($product_info['price'], $this->session->data['currency']); 

}else {  
 $data['price'] = false;
}
```